# ASP C# - How to get the value of a drop down when selected by user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently I have several enums declared in my models:

```
public enum Size
{
    Round = 1, Square, Oval, Sheet
}

public enum RoundSizes
{
    Six = 1, Eight, Nine, Ten, Twelve, Fourteen
}

public enum SquareSizes
{
    Six = 1, Seven, Nine, Ten, Twelve
}
```

I also have a view that display drop downs for all sizes in enum Size:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Size)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RoundSizes)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.RoundSizes, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SquareSizes)
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.SquareSizes, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

I am quite new to ASP unfortunately. My goal of this application is to have the RoundSizes or SquareSizes drop-down only appear depending on whether the user selected Round or Square in the size drop down while filling out the form. So after you select "Round" from the Size drop down, a new drop down will appear on the same page that will allow you to select : Six, Eight, Nine, Ten, Twelve, or Fourteen. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You need to use javascript to respond to client side events (handle the `.change()` even of the SIze dropdownlist and show/hide the relevant dropdown